# python system tray using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, system, system-tray

I want to create a system tray for my application using python tkinter.

can anyone let me know how can I do the same using python tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think python Tkinter can do it alone. You'll probably need to install [some tk extension](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4090), which will be platform-dependant and hard to use from python's bindings.

For completeness, on gtk you'd use [`gtk.StatusIcon`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstatusicon.html)